# How to make active particular toggle

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, datatable

This is my toogle code .Iam getting this HTML from backend . Iam using it in ng-repeat.When I click on a switch and make activate ,all switches become active and my expectation is only that switch become active that is clicked

```
<td class="">
  <label class="switch switch custom-switch" aria-hidden="false">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="agent_approve" ng-click="agent_status(agent_approve,id)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" aria-checked="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <span></span>
  </label>
</td>
```

as i have mentioned that all data is coming from backend . we only save it in tables  and render it on html page 
controller data is

```
$scope.dtInstance = $('#all_driver_datatable').dataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "order": [[0, "desc"]],
                "iDisplayLength": 25,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bPagination": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "sDom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"ipl><"clear">',
                language: {
                    paginate: {
                        next: '<i class="tf right-chevron"></i>',
                        previous: '<i class="tf left-chevron"></i>'
                    }
                },
                aoColumns: [
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.AGENTS_ID' | translate}}", "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "7%"},
                    {
                        "sTitle": "{{'more.agents.IMAGE' | translate}}",
                        "sClass": "ng-cloak",
                        "sWidth": "7%",
                        orderable: false
                    },
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.USERNAME' | translate}}", "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "10%"},
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.NAME' | translate}}", "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "10%"},
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.EMAIL' | translate}}", "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "9%"},
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.PHONE' | translate}}", "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "9%"},
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.DEVICE_TYPE' | translate}}", "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "6%"},
                    {
                        "sTitle": "{{'more.agents.DEVICE_VERSION' | translate}}",
                        "sClass": "ng-cloak",
                        "sWidth": "6%"
                    },
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.TEAM' | translate}}", "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "9%"},
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.STATUS' | translate}}", "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "12%"},
                    {
                        "sTitle": "{{'more.agents.ACTIONS' | translate}}",
                        "sClass": "ng-cloak",
                        orderable: false,
                        "sWidth": "14%"
                    },
                ],
                // "columnDefs": [
                //     {targets: 'no-sort', orderable: false},
                //     {"type": "date-de", targets: 7}
                // ],
                "headerCallback": function (thead, data, start, end, display) {
                    $compile(thead)($scope);
                    $('.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input[type="search"]', '.fancy-table-outer').attr('placeholder', 'Search '+$scope.driverNamedAs).attr('onkeyup', 'showLoader()').focus().after('<div class="tf search"></div>');
                },
                "sAjaxSource": api,
                "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                    $compile(row)($scope);
                    $compile($('#all_driver_datatable thead tr')[0])($scope);
                    hideLoader();
                },
                "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                    hideLoader();
                },
                "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": arr,
                "visible": false
            }
            ]

            }).fnSetFilteringDelay(2000);

            $timeout(function () {
                $compile($('#all_driver_datatable thead tr')[0])($scope);
                $("#all_driver_datatable").show();
                $('table th').css('opacity', '1');
                hideLoader();
            }, 2000);

        }
```

Comment: they must be sharing the same `ng-model`, they have to be different, if you want to activate individual checkboxes, use an array for that

Answer (score 0):

You have the same `ng-model` assigned to all of your checkboxes. So, if one becomes `true`, it makes all the checkboxes as checked.

Change the value of your `ng-model`, for example, use an array instead.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
  <td class="">
    <label class="switch switch custom-switch" aria-hidden="false">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="agent_approve[$index]" ng-click="agent_status(agent_approve,id)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" aria-checked="true" aria-invalid="false">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This way, `agent_approve` will be an array of boolean values, each representing the checked state of the corresponding checkbox.

Comment: This cannot resolve my problem because this html is coming from backend and we save it in table than we render it . There is no use of ng-repeat .

Comment: @user8331237 -- even the server might have been rendering it using some sort of iteration. You can use the index of the server side loop, and it will work just the same.

Comment: no.. we use ajax call and save all data into table and .. as metioned in above controller

Comment: if you have any idea .. kindly guide me