# How to make active particular toggle and the main thing is that all data is coming from backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, datatables

This is my toogle code .Iam getting this HTML from backend and we save it in table then render on html page.When I click on a switch and make activate ,all switches become active and my expectation is only that switch become active that is clicked

My controller data is

```
 $scope.dtInstance = $('#all_driver_datatable').dataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "order": [[0, "desc"]],
                "iDisplayLength": 25,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bPagination": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "sDom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"ipl><"clear">',
                language: {
                    paginate: {
                        next: '<i class="tf right-chevron"></i>',
                        previous: '<i class="tf left-chevron"></i>'
                    }
                },
                aoColumns: [
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.AGENTS_ID' | 
               translate}}", "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "7%"},
                    {
                        "sTitle": "{{'more.agents.IMAGE' | 
                translate}}",
                        "sClass": "ng-cloak",
                        "sWidth": "7%",
                        orderable: false
                    },
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.USERNAME' | 
             translate}}", "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "10%"},
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.NAME' | translate}}", 
               "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "10%"},
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.EMAIL' | translate}}", 
             "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "9%"},
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.PHONE' | translate}}", 
              "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "9%"},
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.DEVICE_TYPE' | 
               translate}}", "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "6%"},
                    {
                        "sTitle": "{{'more.agents.DEVICE_VERSION' | 
                   translate}}",
                        "sClass": "ng-cloak",
                        "sWidth": "6%"
                    },
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.TEAM' | translate}}", 
                 "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "9%"},
                    {"sTitle": "{{'more.agents.STATUS' | translate}}", 
                 "sClass": "ng-cloak", "sWidth": "12%"},
                    {
                        "sTitle": "{{'more.agents.ACTIONS' | 
                   translate}}",
                        "sClass": "ng-cloak",
                        orderable: false,
                        "sWidth": "14%"
                    },
                ],
                // "columnDefs": [
                //     {targets: 'no-sort', orderable: false},
                //     {"type": "date-de", targets: 7}
                // ],
                "headerCallback": function (thead, data, start, end, 
                display) {
                    $compile(thead)($scope);
                    $('.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter 
                  input[type="search"]', '.fancy-table-
                outer').attr('placeholder', 'Search 
               '+$scope.driverNamedAs).attr('onkeyup', 
              'showLoader()').focus().after('<div class="tf search">
              </div>');
                },
                "sAjaxSource": api,
                "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                    $compile(row)($scope);
                    $compile($('#all_driver_datatable thead tr')[0])
                 ($scope);
                    hideLoader();
                },
                "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                    hideLoader();
                },
                "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": arr,
                "visible": false
            }
            ]

            }).fnSetFilteringDelay(2000);

            $timeout(function () {
                $compile($('#all_driver_datatable thead tr')[0])
             ($scope);
                $("#all_driver_datatable").show();
                $('table th').css('opacity', '1');
                console.log($scope.dtInstance);
                hideLoader();
            }, 2000);

        }
```

And the HTML iam using  is
,ain problem is that whnever i click on a single toggle ,it gives the value of particular but make all green

```
    <td class="">
    <label class="switch switch custom-switch" aria-hidden="false">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="agent_approve[$index]" ng-
    click="agent_status(agent_approve,id)" class="ng-pristine ng-
   untouched ng-valid" aria-checked="true" aria-invalid="false">
   <span></span>
    </label>
  </td>
```

Comment: Please take a look at Angular DataTables, whuch is directives for jQuery DataTable. I cannot say if that is the case here, but DataTables and angular does not work together, they both manipulate the DOM and at best you will experience race conditions.

Comment: Besides that, you should stop double posting, i.e question spamming, you already asked this 1½ day ago here -> **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347223/how-to-make-active-particular-toggle**

Comment: there is any method .. i can convert datatables data into json ??